# Using mcrypt_create_iv on PHP IIS

Tags: php, iis, mcrypt, pbkdf2

I'm trying to set up password salting on our website, and found the PBKDF2 functions at https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm
When I try it, I get:

> Fatal error: mcrypt_create_iv(): Could not gather sufficient random
>   data in include\PBKDF2.php on line 23

I'm not sure if I need to do anything to make this work. It's running on IIS7.5

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using PHP 5.3.6, which apparently has a bug with mcrypt_create_iv().
Switched to the latest version 5.4.7 and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still facing error:

> Fatal Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv()

Please check the phpversion and correspondingly make sure to go to `php.ini` file and add the line or uncomment:

```
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

I was able to get solution from here http://tech.domainstack.in/how-to-enable-mcrypt-on-the-server/