# Exception in random_bytes_mcrypt.php line 73

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I try to host laravel application but I get this error:

```
Exception in random_bytes_mcrypt.php line 73:
Could not gather sufficient random data
```

[image]

[image]

PHP version 5.6

Comment: you need to post your code

Comment: there is no code, it's the default installation of laravel 5.1, it's just a test and it's not work

Comment: not that it might matter.. but are you using Homestead or what is the environment?

Comment: do you have `APP_KEY` set in your .env file?   can you also give us the entire error?  (everything below the error text you mentioned above)

Comment: which version of PHP you are using?

Comment: Raise a bug with the Laravel developers. Though this actually sounds like a system configuration problem; you don't have enough entropy in whatever source feeds this file.

Comment: And you're sure it's PHP 5.6 and not 5.3.6? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12602894/451969

Comment: yes I'm sur, i use 5.6

Comment: I try to host application in panel.lws.fr

Comment: This was a [known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55169) fixed around 5.4+.

Comment: No i use php 5.6 and i'm sur

Comment: Here's the line in the Paragonie random_compat library:  https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/blob/master/lib/random_bytes_mcrypt.php#L73 Seems like something that should be raised with the Laravel project developers, as @BarryTheHatchet suggests.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ht9r9.png

Comment: can I see more of the 1st screen shot?  Curious to see the entire stack trace